# An order isomorphism between lattices is a lattice isomorphism

Tags: lattice-orders

Suppose that $(X, \leq_X)$ and $(Y, \leq_Y)$ are ordered sets. Let $T:(X, \leq_X) \rightarrow (Y, \leq_Y)$ be an order isomorphism. Is it true that $T$ is a lattice isomorphism?

I have this question because I couldn't follow the explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329709/order-isomorphism-maps-f-g-to-tf-tg) by Josse. Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: ProofWiki: [Order Isomorphism on Lattice preserves Lattice Structure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_Isomorphism_on_Lattice_preserves_Lattice_Structure)